# How to prevent Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu from closing when click inside

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to prevent Bootstrap5 dropdown menu from closing when clicked inside. With Bootstrap 3 the code below works fine but with Bootstrap 5 it's not working.

```
//stop all bootstrap dropdown menu from closing on click inside
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I am working with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>





<script>

//stop all bootstrap dropdown menu from closing on click inside
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

</script>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bootstrap 5, the option **auto-close** defines what happens on click.
In your case, you can add **data-bs-auto-close="outside"** to your dropdown.

See below:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableInside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
    Clickable inside
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableInside">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```